# What is the meaning of alternating in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Psoriasis is a persistent, long-lasting (chronic) disease. You may have periods when your psoriasis symptoms improve or go into remission **alternating** with times your psoriasis worsens.”

does it means, after remission worsening time comes and again remission again worsening. Am I right?

The definition of alternate according to the dictionary is to switch back and forth between two things or activities.

But I don’t know the meaning of **switch back and forth**

So, actually I am asking **two questions** marked above in *bold*. by the way, I am not a native speaker of English

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

> I read a lot. I alternate between fiction and non-fiction.

If I alternate between reading fiction books and non-fiction books, I read a fiction book, then a non-fiction book, then a fiction book again, and so on.

To switch back and forth indeed means the same thing, but I see it usually used when someone physically switches between two things:

> He switched back and forth between his computer and his telephone.

Comment: I think _back-and-forth_ is used plenty often enough with non-physical things: _As the work week came to a close, his mind wandered back-and-forth between his work and his Friday night date_.

Comment: Although the mind does not literally walk around, you _do_ use the verb _wander_, which implies a physical activity. So it seems that even when used in a figurative sense, it _is_ linked to physical movement.

Comment: Interesting take. I think of someone in a moment of indecisiveness going _back and forth_ between two alternatives in their mind. Even then, I use the word _go_, as if the mind is figuratively walking somewhere to and fro. Interesting for sure.

Comment: That is an interesting take, although I can't see it as fully backing up the position that back and forth is typically linked to physical movement. Going back to switch: while of course switching can be used to describe a physical activity (square dancing does a lot of it, for example), it's not clear to me that the concept of switching per se therefore derives from a physical activity as figurative uses of wandering or going probably do. I might switch back and forth between topics of discussion, or insurance providers, for example.